# How to change the LAMP password?

Tags: passwords, xampp, lampp

I accidentally set my password for xampp pages in lampp.

How do I change/remove the password (for lampp) ?

My lampp version is 1.8.1, under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter sudo /opt/lampp/lampp security.This will ask you to change the password. If you are a sudoer you dont need to enter the old password.
If this does not solve your problem visit this link [a link] http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=193142&sid=d84e4bebb8b922f339a2b1b1e812a05a

Comment: Even after researching i got only to know how to change password. But nowhere i found how to remove it.